# Only rendering 3 items inside FlatList

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I want to render only 3 of my items inside a `FlatList`. Latter when I click the text new item will be rendered.

here is the example code:

```
export default class FlatListBasics extends Component {
renderNewItem = () => {
// do something here
}
      render() {
        return (
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <FlatList
              data={[
                {key: 'Devin'},
                {key: 'Jackson'},
                {key: 'James'},
                {key: 'Joel'},
                {key: 'John'},
                {key: 'Jillian'},
                {key: 'Jimmy'},
                {key: 'Julie'},
              ]}
              renderItem={({item}) => <Text onPress={this.renderNewItem}>{item.key}</Text>}
            />
          </View>
        );
      }
```

So how I can achieve this?
        }

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [`Array.prototype.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) to control amount of the data rendered. Set a count in your state and then add 1 to it every time you pressed the button. This way you are not dependent on how do you load your data. You can either use a local data source or a remote one with an API. Another key point is to add a `keyExtractor` so the re-render will be more performance.

**Example**

```
const data = [
  {key: 'Devin'},
  {key: 'Jackson'},
  {key: 'James'},
  {key: 'Joel'},
  {key: 'John'},
  {key: 'Jillian'},
  {key: 'Jimmy'},
  {key: 'Julie'},
];
class FlatListBasics extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      itemsCount: 3 
    };
  }
  renderNewItem = () => {
    if (this.state.itemsCount < data.length) {
      this.setState((prevState) => ({ itemsCount: (prevState.itemsCount + 1) }));
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <FlatList
          data={data.slice(0, this.state.itemsCount)}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.key;}
          renderItem={({ item }) => <Text onPress={this.renderNewItem}>{item.key}</Text>}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I guess this is what I am looking for, I will accept after test that in my code, thanks

Answer (score 1):

So first prepare your 3 items data in your constructor:

```
let state = {
    data = [{key: "Devin"}, {key: "Jackson"}, {key: "James"}]
}
```

And render your `FlatList`.

Then, in `renderItem`, you would have an `onPress` that will add an item to your `data`

```
renderItem = () => {
    <TouchableOpacity onPress=() => { this.setState({data: this.state.data.pushBack(/*your new item here*/)}) }
    </TouchableOpacity>
}
```

`this.setState` will force everything to rerender, therefore it will show the new added item.

Comment: this will works, 1 more question, saying the data coming from backend with 20 items, so I should store the first 3 item into my state.data then feed state.data to flatlist. after I press the button, I call setState to add more data to state.data?

Comment: @2r83 correct. So you receive the 20 items and then store them locally (or just in some global variable or in the state). Then, on each press (since you want it to happen onPress), you remove the first item from your server data and add it to your displayed data. Take into consideration that `data` in my answer is the displayed data